# Lifecycle of components with children

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm confused about where to call various aspects of childrens' lifecycle in composite components. I do not see the way how one Component may be used in other Component which in turn may be used in other etc. Unfortunately Michael Bolins - 'Closure The Definitive Guide' doesn't gives any examples. Neither I cannot find any such examples in Closure demos or in the internet.

Here is my component with children:

```
goog.provide('MainToolbar');

goog.require('goog.ui.Button');
goog.require('goog.ui.Container');
goog.require('goog.ui.FlatButtonRenderer');

MainToolbar = function(){
    goog.ui.Container.call(this, goog.ui.Container.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);    
};
goog.inherits(MainToolbar, goog.ui.Container);

MainToolbar.prototype.createDom = function(){
    var this_ = this;
    // Pre-render the container, just to do something different.
    //hc.render(goog.dom.getElement('main-buttons'));
    goog.array.forEach(
        ['Happy', 'Sleepy', 'Doc', 'Bashful', 'Sneezy', 'Grumpy', 'Dopey'],
        function(item) {
            var c = new goog.ui.Button(item,
                goog.ui.FlatButtonRenderer.getInstance());          
            c.addClassName('goog-inline-block');
            c.setId(item);         
            this_.addChild(c, true);
        });
};
```

Here is how I call it:

```
mainToolbar = new MainToolbar();
mainToolbar.render(goog.dom.getElement('main-buttons'));
```

The problem is that MainToolbar.prototype.createDom calls itself second time and I get

```
Uncaught Error: The object already contains the key "Happy" from myApp
```

Probably the addChild should be put to some other place, but to where? Constructor? enterDocument? And how it is supposed to scale?

UPDATE: Here is callstack showing the second call:

```
MainToolbar.createDom (MainToolbar.js:70)
goog.ui.Component.addChildAt (component.js:1009)
goog.ui.Component.addChild (component.js:913)
(anonymous function) (MainToolbar.js:81)
goog.array.forEach.goog.NATIVE_ARRAY_PROTOTYPES.goog.array.ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_.forEach.l (array.js:179)
MainToolbar.createDom (MainToolbar.js:70)
goog.ui.Component.render_ (component.js:664)
goog.ui.Component.render (component.js:621)
```

Comment: "The problem is that MainToolbar.prototype.createDom calls itself second time"
- When is this second time happening?

Comment: @ne8il, I've added callstack, please see UPDATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addChildAt method of goog.ui.Component (inherited by goog.ui.Container) has a check to make sure that if you are trying to render the child control, the parent must also be rendered. It does this by checking the existence of "this.element_":

(line 1023 in my copy of component.js)

```
if (!this.element_) {
  this.createDom();
}
```

This is where it's getting duplicated. When you override the createDom method, you need to either manually create this property:

```
this.element_ = goog.dom.createDom('div');
```

or just let the inherited class do the work :

```
goog.base(this, 'createDom');
```

Generally at the top of the method before any work is done.